# Ordered Traversal on Titan Using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

When using Titan `1.0.0` and Elasticsearch as my indexing backend I create the following Mixed index:

```
TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open("titan-cassandra-es.properties");
TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();

PropertyKey typeKey = management.makePropertyKey("TYPE").dataType(String.class).make();
PropertyKey degreeKey = management.makePropertyKey("DEGREE").dataType(Long.class).make();

management.buildIndex("byTypeDegree", Vertex.class)
    .addKey(typeKey)
    .addKey(degreeKey)
    .buildMixedIndex("search");

management.commit();
```

The goal is so that I can search for vertices of a specific **type** and order them using the **degree**. I believe the following should achieve that:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("TYPE", "person").order.by("DEGREE");
```

However the above traversal is clearly not using the Index as I get the following error:

```
Could not execute query since pre-sorting requires fetching more than 1000000 elements. Consider rewriting the query to exploit sort orders
```

What's odd is that I have confirmed that elastic search can answer my query very quickly. Using the following query directly to Elasticsearch:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/titan/byTypeDegree/_search?size=80' -d '
{
    "sort" : [
        { "DEGREE" : {"order" : "desc"}}
    ],
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 { "term" : {"TYPE" : "person"}} 
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get the results I need:

```
"hits": [

    "_index": "titan",
    "_type": "byTypeDegree",
    "_id": "izaqnk",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "TYPE": "http://mindmaps.io/person",
      "DEGREE": 140
    },
    "sort": [
      140
    ]
 },
 {
    "_index": "titan",
    "_type": "byTypeDegree",
    "_id": "8j5oxk",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "TYPE": "http://mindmaps.io/person",
      "DEGREE": 112
    },
    "sort": [
      112
    ]
 },
...
```

So why can't Titan execute the traversal using the index ? Am I incorrectly creating the index or is the traversal incorrect ?

The current questions regarding this issue appear to be about Titan `0.5.x` so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: you are creating byTypeAndDegree in Titan and querying for byTypeDegree in elastic ? Shouldn't they be the same string ?

Comment: Typing error. Fixed now. Thanks @Niloct.

Comment: Should `DEGREE` be declared as a numeric data type instead of `String.class`?

Comment: Another typing error. Thanks @JasonPlurad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my issue. Which may actually be an oversight on Titan's part. I modified my index construction to be :

```
TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open("titan-cassandra-es.properties");
TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();

PropertyKey typeKey = management.makePropertyKey("TYPE").dataType(String.class).make();
PropertyKey degreeKey = management.makePropertyKey("DEGREE").dataType(Long.class).make();

management.buildIndex("byTypeDegree", Vertex.class)
    .addKey(typeKey, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()))
    .addKey(degreeKey)
    .buildMixedIndex("search");

management.commit();
```

By explicitly stating that the `typeKey` is a `Mapping.STRING.asParameter()` I was able to execute the traversal:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("TYPE", "person").order.by("DEGREE");
```

very quickly. It's odd that this seems to be a restriction when wanting to use `order().by()` on indexed numeric ranges.